# Why is my "if not" statement failing in Python

Tags: python

In this tic-tac-toe game, I created a def is_board_empty. This is supposed to prevent the computer as well as the human from putting their 'X' or 'O' in an occupied place. I have checked the def separately and it seems to return the correct value. The thing is, even with this method, I can still place my character in an occupied place, which led me to believe that the statement `if not board_layout[position]` doesn't work. I can't understand why.

```
import random

board_layout = [
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' '
]


class Increment:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Increment.count += 1


def human_turn():
    position = -1

    while True:
        try:
            position = int(input("Enter a position from 1-9\n"))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if position > 9 or position < 1:
            continue
        if not is_board_empty(position): # this doesn't seem to be doing anything
            print('That space is taken')
            continue
        else:
            position = int(position) - 1
            board_layout[position] = 'O'
            Increment.count += 1
            print(Increment.count)
            board()
            break


def computer_turn():
    while True:
        try:
            if Increment.count == 9:
                break
            position = random.randint(1, 9)
            if is_board_empty(position):
                board_layout[position] = 'X'
                board()
                Increment.count += 1
                print(Increment.count)
                break
            else:
                continue
        except:
            continue


def is_board_empty(position):
    if 'X' in board_layout[position] or 'O' in board_layout[position]:
        return False
    else:
        return True


while is_winner() is None and Increment.count != 9:
    human_turn()
    print('\n')
    computer_turn()
    print('\n')
```

Comment: It would help if you could cut irrelevant code out of your example, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It looks like you check whether the position is empty, then subtract one from the position before assigning to it. Are you checking one position to the right, perhaps?

Comment: Via Liad Kehila: "A general solution to those kinds of problem would be to use a debugger (you can search online on how to use the pycharm debugger or pdb for example), going line by line will likely help you figure out what's wrong here.

I can also help you a little more if you still struggle to find what's the problem, though learning to use a debugger is a very useful skill."

Comment: For instance, we can't run your code because your ```is_winner()``` function is not included, by example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**
The board is made as a list with an index 0-8. Your function checks the board with index 1-9. For the human's turn, before you use the is_board_empty function, you should subtract 1 from the user's input.For the computer's turn, you should change the random number limits to 0 and 8. Here is the code:

In human turn:

```
position = (int(input("Enter a position from 1-9\n")))-1
```

In computer turn:

```
position = random.randint(0, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array for your bord is indexed from 0-8 while position is between 1-9.

Comment: To add to what @marcusoft said, your if statement `if not is_board_empty(position):` is looking at one position to the right. You need to subtract 1 from position before you check.

Comment: You have a few places where position is not represented correctly. In the human_turn, you are not subtracting 1 from position before you check. In the computer_turn, you are picking random number from 1 thru 9 instead of 0 thru 8. Make those corrections to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for positions 1 thru 9. Your board_layout list is range of 0 thru 8. In your code, you are one position off in both computer_turn and human_turn. I have highlighted the areas in your code that needs to be fixed.

Error sections in your code:

```
def human_turn():
         if not is_board_empty(position): # this doesn't seem to be doing anything
        #the above if statement is checking for wrong position. 
        #It has to be position -1 instead of position

def computer_turn():
            position = random.randint(1, 9)
        #you need to use randint(0,8) instead of (1,9)
```

Fix these two sections and your code should work correctly.